# Is it possible to use windows compatible amd drivers on linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, amd-radeon

I have an acer nitro 5 which uses amd ryzen and radeon rx 560x gpu. After install ubuntu on my device I found that that gpu driver installed was that of Baffin and Raven ridge. It still worked I guess. But things changed when I installed kali linux. It didnt auto install any drivers and there are no linux compatible drivers for amd radeon or vega 8 mobile. So is it possible to install the windows drivers I use on my pc onto linux too. If then please explain. Also how does the ubuntu use the raven ridge.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't use Windows drivers with Linux.  Radeon drivers should be readily available.  It's based on Debian Testing, so if it isn't in Kali's repository, check the Debian and Debian non-free repositories.  That said, please be aware that Kali is not a general purpose Linux distro.  It's a special purpose distro intended for use by advanced users.  Based on the details in your question, it doesn't sound like you have the Linux expertise, yet, to effectively set up and use Kali.  If you aren't installing it for the purpose of forensics or security testing, it's the wrong distro.

Comment: Kali is known to have trouble with many drivers. Kali is intended for [penetration testing](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me): you put it on a USB stick, walk into a company, and hack their computers.  Kali is not "what the experts use" or "what all hackers use", no matter what you read on some forums. So stay with Ubuntu; you'll have all the hacking tools Kali also has (though you may need to install them from the package manager) and none of the driver trouble.

Comment: Hi thanks for telling me this. I saw on some posts that you should use kali if u want to learn hacking. I will stick to ubuntu for now as per your advice. So I searched the amd drivers for amd radeon rx 560x and couldnt find a linux based driver for it. Ubuntu installed something called Amd raven in it. Any idead what that might be.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use windows compatible ... drivers on linux

No.

Hardware drivers are specific to an operating system family - and often more specific than that.

There are more nuanced answers in the case of, say, running Linux under Windows using a VM or WSL - but I don't think that's what you are asking.